# How to add dynamic slider in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, slider

I'm using laravel and I want use slider in my index page, here is my slider code:

```
<div class="home-slideshow">
                  <div id="home_main-slider" class="carousel slide  main-slider">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="carousel-1"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      @foreach($banners as $banner)
                      <!-- slider images -->
                      <div class="item image active">
                        <img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$banner->slider_one}}" height="362" alt="{{$banner->slider_one_title}}" title="Image Slideshow">
                        <div class="slideshow-caption position-right">
                          <div class="slide-caption">
                            <div class="group-caption">
                              <div class="content">
                                <span class="title_2">
                                  {{$banner->slider_one_title}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="caption">
                                  {{$banner->slider_one_description}}
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="flex-action"><a class="btn" href="{{$banner->slider_one_link}}">{{$banner->slider_one_button}}</a></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- slider images -->
                      @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I can get my image, text,etc. but i want to know to get slider buttons work?

[image]

## UPDATE

this is my latest code base on suggestions, but still slides not changing,

***I think something in bottom of slider codes has to change (where next and previous codes are)***

```
<div class="home-slideshow">
                  <div id="home_main-slider" class="carousel slide  main-slider">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      @foreach($banners as $key => $banner)
                       <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="{{$key}}" class="carousel-1">
                       </li>
                      @endforeach
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      @foreach($banners as $banner)
                      <!-- slider images -->
                      @if ($loop->first)
                      <div class="item image active">
                      @else
                      <div class="item image">
                      @endif
                        <img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$banner->slider_one}}" height="362" alt="{{$banner->slider_one_title}}">
                        <div class="slideshow-caption position-right">
                          <div class="slide-caption">
                            <div class="group-caption">
                              <div class="content">
                                <span class="title_2">
                                  {{$banner->slider_one_title}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="caption">
                                  {{$banner->slider_one_description}}
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              <div class="flex-action"><a class="btn" href="{{$banner->slider_one_link}}">{{$banner->slider_one_button}}</a></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- slider images -->
                      @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="icon-next"></span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: `<div class="active"> ` That's the problem.  `@foreach($images as $image)@if ($loop->first) <div class="active>" ...... @endif`

Comment: @RutvijKothari in which part?

Comment: `@foreach($banners as $banner)
                      <!-- slider images -->
                      <div class="item image active">` <-- this one

Comment: @RutvijKothari ok i made this now `@if ($loop->first)                      <div class="item image active">                      @else                      <div class="item image">                      @endif`  but what about buttons? they are link to nothing

Comment: I don't get it? What button does and each slider has its own button, right?

Comment: @RutvijKothari updated my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158127/discussion-between-rutvij-kothari-and-mafortis).

Comment: Solution was found [here](https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-add-dynamic-slider-in-laravel-part-1) and [here](https://irando.co.id/articles/how-to-add-dynamic-slider-in-laravel-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="carousel-1">
 </li>
</ol>
```

change to

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
@foreach($banners as $key => $banner)
 <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="{{$key}}" class="carousel-1">
 </li>
@endforeach
</ol>
```

because you need indicator for each slide.
and do not use active class for each slide, so remove active class and only use for certain key.